# PHP Error Notice Undefined index: field_ta_rows in textarea/ft.textarea.php

Tags: custom-fields, php-errors, textarea

I have this PHP warning noticed that's appearing in one of my channels and I'm not sure what the issue is. My channel has 9 custom fields; 4 grid fields, 3 text input fields, a text area field and a file upload field. I don't think there is anything overly complicated happening with these fields. I have Field Pack installed but i'm not using it within this channels custom fields. Has anyone else had a similar issue? What are some things I should look out for that might be causing this to appear?

Notes: This was a fresh install of EE 2.9.2. Field Pack version is 2.2.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_ta_rows
Filename: textarea/ft.textarea.php
Line Number: 77
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this just now and fixed it by changing the number of rows assigned to the gird textarea field. Possibly related to this Structure bug (if you're using that?): http://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/18867-bug-with-assets-and-grid-and-a-structure-field-type

Comment: Yes, I am using Structure. I was able to resolve the issue before I saw your response. I removed the custom field and created it again from scratch and that seemed to fix it.